# How to select with IN operator with DenoDB

Tags: postgresql, deno, in-operator, denodb

So basically I would like to execute a SQL statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM flights WHERE departure in ('Tokio','Berlin');
```

but the official docs don't really show me anything. A similar question on GitHubs Q&A was asked here https://github.com/eveningkid/denodb/discussions/286 but sadly no answers/comments.

I tried

```
.where("departure", "in", ['Tokio','Berlin']);
```

and similar but nothing seems to work. Does anybody have an idea? If this is currently not supported can someone point me to another JS orm that works well will Deno which has the functionality?

Comment: `whereIn` seems to do that (found in [sql-translator.ts](https://github.com/eveningkid/denodb/blob/master/lib/translators/sql-translator.ts))

Comment: Ok I don't know why but I get results now. Maybe I overlooked my offset or something. Thanks anyway. Will leave this here so it might help someone who is looking for the IN operator in DenoDB.